# Как выбрать элемент в mongodb по id из get параметров?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Не подставляет `get` переменную в объект, передаваемый в `findOne`. Если просто вставляю `{ id: 2 }` или `let id = 2`  и `{ id: id }`, база возвращает нужный элемент. Мой ключ `id` существует наряду с встроенным `_id`, поиск веду именно по первому. Как передать в базу `get` переменную?

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/", { useNewUrlParser: true });
// Connection URL
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

mongoClient.connect(function(err, client){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    dbClient = client;
    app.locals.db = client.db("socialNetwork");
    app.listen(3002, function(){
        console.log('go');
    });
});

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
 const collection = req.app.locals.db.collection("users");
 const id = req.query.id;
 if(id) {
  collection.findOne({id: id}, function(err, user){
         if(err) return console.log(err);
         res.send(user);
     });
 }else {
  collection.find({}, {_id:0}).toArray(function(err, users){
         if(err) return console.log(err);
         res.send(users)
     });
 }
 
});

process.on("SIGINT", () => {
    dbClient.close();
    process.exit();
});
```

```js
"_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec3e670a474c579cc6e3d81"
    },
    "name": "Alexander Tonkonog",
    "avatar": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cdcfcdf8989e433a230201c171b6eb08?s=58&r=g&d=mm",
    "friends": [2],
    "id": 1,
    "active": "26.02.20 20:52",
    "tag": ["Popular"],
    "type": "user",
    "follow": [1, 2],
    "data": {
        "birthday": "29.08.1997",
        "city": "Krasnodar",
        "sex": "male",
        "education": "KubSU",
        "family": null,
        "language": ["Russian", "English"]
    }
```

Comment: Судя из документации может, более того это рекомендованный метод, если помимо встроенного id вы используете ваш собственный id, но указано, что в данном случае может подойти метод findById(id), я более чем уверен, что это не сработает, но попробовать стоит. И так же насколько мне известно, вы можете не использовать встроенные _id, а использовать ваш. Это опция useCreateIndex в значении false, но если в схеме не будет найден пункт _id в консоли будет warning. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/", { useNewUrlParser: true });
// Connection URL
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  dbClient = client;
  app.locals.db = client.db("socialNetwork");
  app.listen(3002, function () {
    console.log('go');
  });
});

app.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const collection = req.app.locals.db.collection("users");
  const id = req.params.id;
  if (id) {
    try {
      const user = await collection.findOne({ _id: id }) // вот тут поменяйте на _id
      res.send(user);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  } else {
    try {
      const users = await collection.find()
      res.send(users)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }

  }

});

process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  dbClient.close();
  process.exit();
});
```

Comment: мне нужно искать именно по id, этот ключ существует в каждом объекте наряду с  _id, просто ввожу поиск по {id: 2} - мне находит нужный элемент

Answer (score 1):

по какой-то причине, пакет mongodb для node js не может искать через find по id (в консоли можно искать как по _id, так и по id).